# How to use template parameters in wiki syntaxhighlight?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki-extensions, wikimedia

I would like to use Template parameters within syntaxhighlight. For instance, something like:

```
 <syntaxhighlight lang="scala">
 val x: Boolean = {{{xVal}}}
 val y: Boolean = {{{yVal}}} | x
 </syntaxhighlight>
```

Where `xVal` and `yVal` are the template parameters to be replaced. The content is multiline and may contain pipe characters, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`#tag`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Miscellaneous):

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|lang=scala|
val x: Boolean = {{{xVal}}}
val y: Boolean = {{{yVal}}} {{!}} x
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

now the content should be the second param, as follows:

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{code|}}}|lang=cpp|}}
```

for the question, it should be:

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|
val x: Boolean = {{{xVal}}}
val y: Boolean = {{{yVal}}} {{!}} x
|lang=scala}}
```